# How to position the .container without moving the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to centerezi the .container, but keeping the canvas at place. How can I achieve that?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <input type="text"/>
 <input type="text"/>
</div>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    overflow: hidden;
}


.container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 150px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("cv");
let width = window.innerWidth * 0.99;
let height = window.innerHeight * 0.97;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

Comment: I have just tweaked little bit of your code by applying `transform` property. Please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have update the css. If you have any query feel free to ask :)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cv");
let width = window.innerWidth * 0.99;
let height = window.innerHeight * 0.97;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas#cv {
  background: #1b1b5d;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I still have the overflow, and my .container still not in the center :(

Comment: what  I show you it doesnot have any overflow and it centered. please follow exact what I did. you need to add a fixed width for your wrapper class to make your conainter in center

Comment: I pasted it exactly. :(

Comment: please give me a screenshot of your screen i will fix it for you

Comment: I found what was the problem! I had a little typo in the link to my CSS. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for your patient and helping :))

Comment: its my pleasure . knock me whenever you face a problem. and tnx for accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one in your css:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cv");
let width = window.innerWidth * 0.99;
let height = window.innerHeight * 0.97;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

```css
html, body {
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
 overflow: hidden;
}



#cv {
 padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    background: green;

}

.container{

 padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin: 50px auto 10px auto;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="forhelp.css">
 <title>CANVAS IN CENTER</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <input type="text"/>
 <input type="text"/>
</div>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `transform:translate(-50%,-50%)` to make it vertical and horizontal center

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cv");
let width = window.innerWidth * 0.99;
let height = window.innerHeight * 0.97;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
#cv {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
```

Comment: @BudaÖrs Glad that Icould help  you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.contianer {
 position: fixed;
}
```

By using fixed property you fix it according to view port.
if you  just want to use it as per parent
then your soltion should work

Comment: I want to use it, as a background.

Comment: use z-index: -1 with position absolute it will go inn background

Comment: It does not work. The .container is still in the left up corner.

Comment: Background of which tag?

Comment: The canvas is the background. I want it to cover the full view port without overflow.

Comment: And I wan the .container to be in the center.